# Can I include a Table/Figure which is mentioned on the "discussion" section, after the Conclusion section?

Tags: paper-submission

Can I include a Table/Figure which is mentioned on the "discussion" section, after the Conclusion section? I have a large figure, which is causing a big blank gap as I have to put it in a whole page.

Comment: This depends on where you want to publish it. But an Appendix/Annex is pretty common.

Comment: Discussion conclusion, further work is a common order...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are submitting to a journal that expects "camera-ready" copy, it doesn't matter. They'll reformat it anyway. Put it where it fits in the narrative, to make life easy for reviewers.